# What happens to my data after hitting the break key in Stata?

Tags: stata

Suppose I had the following structure for a script called mycode.do in Stata

```
-some code to modify original data-

save new_data, replace

-some other code to perform calculations on new_data-
```

Now suppose I press the *break* button to stop Stata after it has saved new_data in the script. My understanding is that Stata will undo the changes made to the data if it is interrupted with the break button before it has finished. Following such interruption, will Stata erase new_data.dta from memory if it didn't exist initially (or revert it back to its original form if it already existed before mycode.do was executed)?

Answer (score 2):

Stata documentation says "After you click on Break, the state of the system is the same as if you had never issued the original command." However, it sounds as if you expect that it treats an entire do-file as a "command". I do not believe this is the case. I believe once the save is completed, then the file new_data has been replaced, and Stata is not able to revert the file to the version before the save.

The Stata Reference Manual also says, in the documentation for Stata release 13, **[R] 16.1.4 Error handling in do-files**, "If you press Break while executing a do-file, Stata responds as though an error has occurred, stopping the do-file." Example 4 discusses this further and seems to support my interpretation.

This seems to me to have interesting implications for Stata "commands" that are implemented as ado files.